# ¿Cómo puedo agregar un bucle?

Tags: c

Estoy desarrollando un programa que me diga cuáles días corresponden a *Semana Santa*, pero no sé hacer un bucle para que aumenten los años hasta donde diga el usuario. Tampoco sé cómo hacer que el usuario elija las columnas y tampoco hacer que aparezcan.

Código de ejemplo:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
  printf(Dia_pascua(2016));
}

int Dia_pascua(temporada) {
  int a, b, c, d, e, n, q;

  a = temporada % 19;
  b = temporada % 4;
  c = temporada % 7;
  d = (19 * a + 24) % 30;
  e = (2 * b + 4 * c + 6 * d + 5) % 7;
  n = (22 + d + e);

  if (n > 31) {
    int inicio = n - 38;
    int dia = n - 31;
    printf("La semana santa inicia el %i de abril", inicio);
    printf("\nLa semana santa termina el %i de abril\n", dia);
  } else if (n <= 31) {
    int inicio = n - 7;
    printf("La semana santa inicia el %i de marzo\n", inicio);
    printf("nLa semana santa termina el %i de marzo\n", n);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar 3 tipos de bucles, te dejo una explicación arriba de cada uno.

El bucle `for`: el primer parámetro declara una variable, normalmente en valor 0, el segundo parámetro es tu primera variable y hasta donde debe llegar, es otro parámetro que debes ingresar vos, el tercer parámetro i++ hace crecer tu primer parámetro para que el bucle llegue a su fin.

```
for(int i =0; i < 10, i++)
{
 //tu lógica aquí
}
```

Bucle `while`: este es para que el bucle sea infinito hasta que la condición deje de ser verdadera.

```
//Ejemplo mientras 1 < 100 o puedes poner un booleano y si la condición es true siempre va a estar dando vueltas el ciclo

while(Condicion) 
{
//Tu logica
}

// este ciclo es igual que el igual pero su diferencia es que siempre ejecuta el código y luego corrobora la condición que sea verdadera o falsa.

do
{
  //tu logica
}
while(Condicion);
```

Todo esto aplica en la mayoría de los lenguajes de programación, la documentación es fácil de encontrar en cualquier lenguaje.

Saludos

Comment: Para próximas respuestas, por favor, revisa la sintaxis... C es sensible al uso de mayúsculas... y a la falta de **punto y coma**. Me he tomado la molestia de arreglar tu respuesta porque está como aceptada... en otro caso te habrías llevado algún negativo

Comment: no respondes a la elección de columnas y for(int i =0; i < 10, i++), por qué 10?

Comment: Hola Eferion, lo voy a tener en cuenta, gracias.